# About unpack in fennel-lang

Tags: group-by, lisp, config, neovim

Recently, I used fennel to write neovim config, and I couldn’t understand the usage of unpack when referring to someone’s project.

```
(fn group-by [n seq ?from]
  (fn f [seq i]
    (let [i (+ i n)
          j (+ i n -1)]
      (when (< i (length seq))
        (values i (unpack seq i j)))))
  (let [start-idx (if (nil? ?from) 1 ?from)]
    (values f seq (- start-idx n))))
```

I read the fennel referenece, not found this usage of unpack.

Answer (score 0):

`unpack` seems to be a way to take a table of values and unpack them as individual values inside an expression:

```
(let [(x y z) (unpack [10 9 8])]
  (+ x y z)) ; => 27
```

Here above, `unpack` works on a list of three elements (a single value) and returns 3 values (10, 9 and 8), which are bound to `x` `y` and `z` respectively thanks to the `let` binding.

Usually, you can call `values` as follows to return multiple values:

```
(values 1 2 3)
```

But in your case, `(values i (unpack ...))` is a form that returns multiple values where the amount of values to return is not know in avance and depends on the size of the list/table being given to `unpack` during execution.